# Django retry if the database service is down

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I use postgres database, and deploy my django with uwsgi and nginx

if the postgres service is not running before uwsgi and nginx , It will cause error

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Host is down
    Is the server running on host "192.168.1.21" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I want to know can I retry to start the nginx and uwsgi until the postgres service is running  ?

Comment: You restart a database service during each deploy? This is uncommon.

Comment: @serg It might happen on server reboot.